# TypeScript: Duplicate identifier in function type

Tags: compiler-errors, typescript

When trying to compile:

```
function foo(f: (number, number)=>boolean) {}
```

I get the error:

```
Duplicate identifier 'number'.
```

Why? What I'm intending to state is that `f` is a function that takes two arguments, each of type `number`, and returns a `boolean`. How do I state that?

For reference, the following do compile:

```
function foo2(f: (number) => boolean) { }

function foo3(f: (a: number, b: number) => boolean) { }

function foo4(f: (number, string) => boolean) { }
```

But the following does not (it generates exactly the same error, `Duplicate identifier 'number'`):

```
function foo5(f: (number, number[]) => boolean) { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to name the parameters the function `f` takes in.  So that's why `foo3` works.  `foo2` and `foo4` compile because the compiler takes those as the names and because there's no type assumes `any` type.  They could be rewritten as:

```
function foo2(f: (number: any) => boolean) { }
function foo4(f: (number: any, string: any) => boolean) { }
```

Of course that's some confusing code.

With that in mind `foo` doesn't work because the compiler takes that to mean:

```
function foo(f: (number: any, number: any)=>boolean) {}
```

and yes you have a duplicate identifier `number`.

Comment: Maan, I have to name the arguments? Is there any way around that? Obviously, the variable names are not *logically* required. (i.e., they're entirely erased at compile time.)

Comment: Nope there's no way around it.  On the bright side it provides a good hint to anyone using your code about what's expected.